# Issue opening pdf from VC++ application

Tags: pdf, visual-c++, mfc, shellexecute

I am currently using

```
int nRet=(int)ShellExecute(NULL,
                           _T("open"),
                           _T("\"")+cPathToFile+_T("\""),
                           _T(""),
                           cDir,
                           SW_SHOW);
```

to open a pdf file from my VC++ application. The file opens correctly but then if I try to open another file from the explorer it doesn't show up. If I close the previuos opened file then all works correctly, as if the application was "locking" the pdf viewer.
Is this a normal/known behaviour?

Comment: Could it be a limitation of your registered .pdf viewer?  What viewer are you using?  Can you open a sequence of multiples from Windows Explorer (i.e. take your app out of the equation)?

Comment: I have used both Adobe Acrobat DC and Foxit Reader and they gave me the same problem. I can open multiple files at the same time if I open them from the explorer